# Как экранировать @ в JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

при селекте вида:

```
$('#user@mail.com')
```

браузер выкидывает ошибку:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #user@mail.com

как экранировать символ @ ?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, перед собакой поставить символ \. По крайней мере, вывод спец.символов в строку так происходит в js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#user\\@mail\\.com')
```

Справка тут http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: Точку тоже надо не забыть экранировать, иначе совсем другой селектор будет.

Answer (score 2):

ещё вариант ...

```js
$('[id="user@mail.com"]').text('Введите запрос');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user@mail.com"></div>
```